# jdk1.4 not supporting RowFilter class

Tags: java, swing, jdk1.4

I need to filter JTable based on the the JTextField value by comparing it with a JTable column. I am not able to use RowFilter class because the application is using jdk1.4. Please suggest an alternate option for this.

Comment: JDK 1.4 is ten years old, couldn't you use something less prehistoric ?

Comment: Backport RowFilter.java.

Comment: Consider a newer Java version.

Comment: JDK1.4 reached its end of support in October 2008.  It is not being updated and may have huge gaping known securities holes. You have bigger problems than not having a RowFilter if you keep using JDK1.4. Get rid of it, upgrade to JDK8 today.

Comment: Back in the day, when dinosaurs roamed the earth, we would write code to solve our problems. Okay, really, we did. When I first started we developed a sorting and filtering `TableModel` which basically acted as proxy to a master `TableModel` and applied the required operations by mapping from the proxy indices to the master model's indicies

Comment: *"jdk1.4 not supporting RowFilter class"* Yeah, it's looking from the comments like 'neither will we' support Java 1.4.

Comment: I am working for the client and they use jdk1.4. And they are not ready to upgrade java version as of now. So somebody please help me a solution for this. Please provide me with the code as i need to work on their change request fast.